# How do i install & change themes for gnome in command line

Tags: gnome, 21.10

How do i install & change the theme for gnome? GUI isn't an option for me as i'm using
Custom Ubuntu ISO Creator(also known as cubic) to customize the distro.

even if i try installing Gnome tweaks, it says it can't find the package apparently.

Comment: Maybe this page will provide some insight: https://www.fossmint.com/install-gnome-themes-on-ubuntu/

Comment: thank you, found the solurtion the github page specified :)